# How can I get the foreignkey # to other table?

Tags: php

I am getting trouble on getting the id's(foreign key from the other tables)

[image: data struct sample]

Here's my code from student_log.php

```
<tr class="record" style="text-align:center;">
<td align="center"><a href="get_idno.php?idno=<?php echo $row['idno']; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $row['idno']; ?></a></td>
</tr>
```

And Here's my get_idno.php

```
<?php

$YearNow=Date('Y');
include('../connection/connect.php');
    $idno=$_GET['idno'];
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM studentvotes,student,candidates where idno = '$idno' AND candidates.idno = student.idno AND student.idno = studentvotes.idno AND syearid = $YearNow ");
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>

<tr class="record" style="text-align:center;">
<td align="center" ><?php echo $row['idno']; ?></td>
<td align="center" ><?php echo $row['candid']; ?></td>
<td align="center" ><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
<td align="center" ><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php
            }
                ?>
```

I think because of `$idno=$_GET['idno'];`? Any help please

Comment: what is your question???what problem are you facing????

Comment: I want that I can get the information of student table (lastname,firstname,middlename) in studentvotes table.. like in the picture example of my codes is studentvotes.idno = student.idno(which mean under the student , studentvotes can get the information as long that student is one of the foreign key of studentvotes). studentvotes table has candid which is a foreignkey, I also want to get the information of candidates table for the studentvotes

Comment: You need to put a table name before `idno = '$idno'`, because `idno` is in multiple tables.

Comment: You should also use parameters in the prepared statement, not variable substitution, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Are you trying to join the table?

Comment: Which table's `idno` are you trying to display in the page?

Answer (score 0):

The query should be something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT c.idno, c.candid, s.firstname, s.lastname
    FROM studentvotes AS sv
    JOIN candidates AS c ON sv.candid = c.candid
    JOIN student AS s ON c.idno = s.idno
    WHERE sv.syearid = :year
    AND sv.idno = :idno");
$stmt->bindParam(':year', $YearNow);
$stmt->bindParam(':idno', $idno);
$stmt->execute();
```

I had to guess which `idno` you want to display in the result and which `idno` you want to match from the `$_GET` parameter.